Error when compile Eclipse BIRT project from source
I downloaded the project and am trying to build it. I get the following error.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal �[32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:3.1.0:run�[m �[1m(build-api-package)�[m on project �[36morg.eclipse.birt.api�[m: �[1;31mAn Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:�[m
[ERROR] �[1;31m/home/suleiman/git/birt/build/org.eclipse.birt.api/build.xml:30: Manifest file: /home/suleiman/git/birt/build/org.eclipse.birt.api/target/manifest.mf does not exist.�[m
[ERROR] �[1;31maround Ant part ...<ant antfile="build.xml" dir="/home/suleiman/git/birt/build/org.eclipse.birt.api" target="package">... @ 4:104 in /home/suleiman/git/birt/build/org.eclipse.birt.api/target/antrun/build-main.xml�[m
[ERROR] -> �[1m[Help 1]

I checked, the manifest is created if you manually run ant in the directory: org.eclipse.birt.api
But when I run the build of the entire project via maven, I get this error: What is the problem?

How exactly are you building the project? Are you using the Maven Build run configuration?

Asking on the birt github issues might be more likely to get an answer for something like this. But you need to add a lot more details about exactly how you are doing the build, which version of Birt, ...
